# Check if webpage is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I need to make a Ajax call after my webpage is completely loaded , How do i check whether my webpage is completely loaded .

Is document.ready is only solution .

Comment: What is the problem with using that (e.g. Jquery's document ready function)?

Comment: no, it's not the only solution, it's merely the most widely used one.

Comment: `window.onload` is another solution that fires after iframes, images, etc load

Comment: Have you tried to put something like this -> `{{callSomething()}}` in the end of your page?

Comment: Will document.ready still be called if any javascript gives error.

Answer (score 1):

If by completely loaded, you mean that all the resources of the page are loaded too (like images, fonts, etc.), then, [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) is where you need to tie your handler.

If you only care about when the browser finishes constructing your DOM, you need to add the listener to [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: Will document.ready still be called if any javascript gives error.

Comment: DOMContentLoaded event listener will be invoked if there is a JS error after the listener was bound to the event. If before, it won't get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to jQuery's document-ready event (indicating that all of the necessary references have been loaded and that the window is ready), you could probably use something like :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        // Your document is ready, place your code here
});
```

Comment: If any javascript code fails to load will angular.element(document).ready(function ()) still be called